# Is there a case when void main(void) is correct?

Tags: c, program-entry-point

In a book (don't remember which one) they used:

```
void main(void)
```

In school I learned:

```
int main(void)
```

Is there **any case** when `void main(void)` is actually correct? Or at least not explicitly wrong?

EDIT:
According to the proposed answers since C99 it is not correct. What about earlier versions? Is it explicitly wrong or just nothing said about it? Why do C compiler not complain about it?

Comment: Throw away that book, please.

Comment: [What's the correct declaration of main()?](http://c-faq.com/ansi/maindecl.html)

Comment: This is one of the less-common times I must admit your school taught you correctly. And buy a different book.

Comment: Most C references, both online and in books, are *crap*.  My go-to reference since 1986 has been [Harbison & Steele](http://careferencemanual.com/).  Even they have some minor issues, but as a rule it's one of the best C references around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`void main(void)` is allowed by some(all?) C compilers. However, it should not be used anyway. Because at least since C99 is it not allowed. However, I did not find a C compiler which complains about it.

E.g. void.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(void)
{
   printf("hello world");
}
```

`gcc void.c`

Compiles.
Also check http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php

So in conclusion (even though I do not find references): In earliest C versions `void main(void)` was probably not forbidden.

However:
**Without specifying a return value, you just do not now what your program returns. So, standard or not, correct or false, do not use it, because it makes your program non-deterministic.**

Comment: http://users.aber.ac.uk/auj/voidmain.cgi

Comment: Thanks, so it void main() is not allowed in C++ ! And is also wrong in C (even though it still compiles).

Comment: Both C & C++ standard say `int main` but compilers may chose allow allow `void main` - that doesn't mean it will compile in other C or C++ compilers

Answer (score 2):

Never, ever use `void main(void)`. It is not standard.

Always use one of

```
int main(void);

int main();

int main(int argc, char **argv);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

And the best use of said book is to use it to light your first fire for the winter.

Answer (score 2):

Per the C standard

> **C99 §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup**
>
> The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters:
>
> ```
> int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be
>   used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent;<sub>10</sub> or in some other implementation-defined manner.
>
> 10) Thus, int can be replaced by a typedef name defined as int, or the type of argv can be written as `char **argv`, and so on.

The closing clause grants implementations their own vices, which is to say, if a program does not follow this, it is no longer standard-compliant and instead reliant on the implementation for compatibility. If you want your `main()` to work *everywhere*, follow one  of these and you'll be ok.

Comment: Note that "implementation-defined" means that the compiler must  document that `void main()` is a legal signature; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.